# How to usea depth level of nested EF Core list, child?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nested, multi-level

I'm using EF Core and I have one list. I have a level field in Response and I want incremental levels for each include. Example below. How can I do it ?

https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb75d8f7

if my include finder code is;

```
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetTreeAsync(Expression<Func<Category, bool>> 
     predicate = null, IList<string> includes = null,
        Func<IQueryable<Category>, IOrderedQueryable<Category>> orderBy = null, bool 
     disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<Category> query = Context.Set<Category>().Where(x => !x.IsDelete);

        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (includes != null)
            query = query.Include(a => a.SubCategories.Where(s => !s.IsDelete))
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.SubCategories.Where(s => !s.IsDelete))
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.SubCategories.Where(s => !s.IsDelete))
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.SubCategories.Where(s => !s.IsDelete))
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.SubCategories.Where(s => !s.IsDelete));

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null) query = orderBy(query);


        string sql = query.ToQueryString();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Response Model;

```
 public class CategoryTreeResponse
 {
    public int Key { get; set; } //id
    public string Title { get; set; } //name
    public int Level { get; set; } //1-2-3-4-....
    public int? CommissionRate { get; set; }
    public int TermDay { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryTreeResponse> Children { get; set; } //submenu
}
```

I use CQRS

Comment: Apart from your original problem, your Category entity would benefit greatly if you added `.HasQueryFilter(c => !c.IsDeleted)` in your model configuration.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to set the `Level` param for each depth level is that it?

Comment: Yes, but that will only happen in Response. Nothing reflected in DB

Comment: Show code, how do you create `CategoryTreeResponse`.